# Why does VS2017 show me the member values of derived classes when I watch the base class object in the watch view?

Tags: c#, watch, class-hierarchy

I have a class hierarchy of 3 classes KlasseA, KlasseB and KlasseC. 
KlasseC inherits from KlasseB.
KlasseB inherits from KlasseA.

Each of these classes have a respective property A,B and C of type int as well as the field a,b and c:

```
public class KlasseA
{
    private int a;

    public int A { get => a; set => a = value; }
}
public class KlasseB: KlasseA
{
    private int b;

    public int B { get => b; set => b = value; }
}
public class KlasseC: KlasseB
{
    private int c;

    public int C { get => c; set => c = value; }
}
```

(I ommitted unecessary constructor and checking logic)

Now I can code the following:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        KlasseA aKlasse;
        KlasseB bKlasse;
        KlasseC cKlasse;
        aKlasse = new KlasseC() { A = 4, B = 5, C = 6 };
        bKlasse = aKlasse as KlasseB;
        cKlasse = aKlasse as KlasseC;
    }

}
```

When I add `aKlasse`, `bKlasse` and `cKlasse` to the watch window, all 3 display the value as of type `KlasseC`, but the type is displayed as `"KlasseA (KlasseC)"` and `"KlasseB (KlasseC)"` and `"KlasseC"` respectively.

After expanding all 3 watch variables, I can see all 3 fields and properties in all of the 3 variables:

```
-aKlasse    {KlasseC}    KlasseA {KlasseC}
 A          4            int
 B          5            int
 C          6            int
 a          4            int
 b          5            int
 c          6            int
-bKlasse    {KlasseC}    KlasseB {KlasseC}
 A          4            int
 B          5            int
 C          6            int
 a          4            int
 b          5            int
 c          6            int
-cKlasse    {KlasseC}    KlasseC
 A          4            int
 B          5            int
 C          6            int
 a          4            int
 b          5            int
 c          6            int
```

I think, that this is not correct, because in the code I could never write

```
aKlasse.C = aKlasse.A;
```

even though the watch window indicates that aKlasse has properties A B and C.

Can somebody confirm or refute my assumption?

Comment: The `aKlasse` variable is referencing a `KlasseC` object and you see all it's fields/properties, as indicated by `"KlasseA (KlasseC)"`

Comment: But it makes no sense for me, if the referencing variable is only of type KlasseA, and in code I can only access KlasseA members, but in the watch window i cann see KlasseC members.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's showing you the *execution* time data - which is far, far more useful than only showing you what you'd be able to see based on what's known at compile-time. Basically, it's showing you "the object that the variable refers to" - and that object in your code is a `KlasseC`, regardless of the type of the variable.

For example, if you had a variable of type `Stream`, but which was *actually* a reference to a `MemoryStream` at execution time, you'd want to be able to look at the list easily without using the watch window to call `Read` etc.

This isn't a bug - it's a feature.

Comment: @WolfgangRoth: The purpose of a debugger is to give you more information. If you had a variable of type `object`, what's more useful - *just* knowing whether the value is null or not, or seeing the *actual data*? Note that the debugger lets you see private fields etc as well... all of this is *useful when debugging*. The fact that you wouldn't be able to access that data directly from other classes doesn't stop it from being useful.